# Why does this assembly language code for matrix addition work only on x64 machines and not 32 bit OS versions?

Tags: assembly, matrix

I am unable to pin point whether its a particular instruction that's doing it or the approach. What must I change? Usually, all these instructions work well everywhere.
However, when I try to add the following:
1 2 3       1 2 3
1 2 3  with 1 2 3
1 2 3       1 2 3

I get:

8 8 8
8 8 8 on a WinXP 32 bit machine,
8 8 8

but I get

2 3 6
2 3 6 on a 64 bit Win7 PC.
2 3 6

I need to get it to work on a 32 bit machine. How do I change my approach? What's going wrong?

Code:

```
.model small
.data
row db ?
col db ?
tot db ?
rows db 10,13,"Enter the no. of rows:$"
cols db 10,13,"Enter the no. of columns:$"
matd1 db 10,13,"Enter the first matrix:",10,13,"$"
matd2 db 10,13,"Enter the second matrix:",10,13,"$"
totald db 10,13,"The sum is:",10,13,"$"
space db " $"
newline db 10,13,"$"
mat1 db 100 dup ("$")
mat2 db 100 dup ("$")
total db 100 dup ("$")

.code
start:
mov ax,@data
mov ds,ax

lea dx,rows
mov ah,09h
int 21h

mov ah,01h
int 21h
sub al,30h
mov row,al

lea dx,cols
mov ah,09h
int 21h

mov ah,01h
int 21h
sub al,30h
mov col,al

mov al,row
mul col
mov tot,al

lea dx,matd1
mov ah,09h
int 21h

mov bl,row
lea si,mat1

top:
mov cl,col

back:
mov ah,01h
int 21h

lea dx,space
mov ah,09h
int 21h

cmp al,41h
jc temp
sub al,07h
temp:
sub al,30h

and al,0fh
mov [si],al
inc si

loop back

lea dx,newline
mov ah,09h
int 21h

dec bl
jnz top

lea dx,matd2
mov ah,09h
int 21h

mov bl,row
lea si,mat2

top1:
mov cl,col

back1:
mov ah,01h
int 21h

lea dx,space
mov ah,09h
int 21h

cmp al,41h
jc temp1
sub al,07h
temp1:
sub al,30h

and al,0fh
mov [si],al
inc si

loop back1

lea dx,newline
mov ah,09h
int 21h

dec bl
jnz top1

lea dx,totald
mov ah,09h
int 21h

lea si,mat1
lea di,mat2
mov bh,row

top2:
mov cl,col

back2:
mov al,[si]
mov bl,[di]
add bl,al

cmp bl,10h
jc temp2

mov dl,31h
mov ah,02h
int 21h

sub bl,10h
cmp bl,0ah
jc ans
add bl,07h
ans:
add bl,30h
mov dl,bl
mov ah,02h
int 21h

jmp temp3

temp2:
mov dl,30h
mov ah,02h
int 21h

cmp bl,0ah
jc ans1
add bl,07h
ans1:
add bl,30h
mov dl,bl
mov ah,02h
int 21h

temp3:

lea dx,space
mov ah,09h
int 21h

inc si
inc di
loop back2

lea dx,newline
mov ah,09h
int 21h

dec bh
jnz top2

mov ah,4ch
int 21h
end start
```

Comment: Please don't ask us to debug hundreds of lines of assembler for you.  Use the debugger to pinpoint the divergence in behaviour.

Comment: How do I do that?
I apologise, I didnt realize the stupidity of it.
How really do I find the difference?

Comment: Step through line-by-line comparing the behaviour to what you expect to happen.  As soon as they diverge, then you've found the (first) bug.

Comment: Given that the code you've included in your question is for a real-mode DOS program I find it surprising that it would even run on a Windows 7 64-bit machine. Unless you're running the program in something like DOSBox, but I see no mention of that in the question.

Comment: Michael I'm using DOSBox indeed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As long as the code is for 16bit real mode DOS and is running on the DOSBox **emulator**,  the problem is in the differences between DOSBox emulator on 64bit and 32bit Windows.

Then, you have to search these differences in the DOSBox bug tracker or home web site.